# passing instance variable from one controller to another to make nested hierarchy work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My nested hierarchy is Subject <--> Page <--> Sections.

I use @subject to list all the pages belonging to that subject and @page to list all sections belonging to that page. 'index' action of respective Subject and Pages controllers are used.

pages_controller.rb

```
def index    
   @pages = @subject.pages.sorted    
end
```

sections_controller.rb

```
def index
    @sections = @page.sections.sorted
end
```

So, now when i want to go back from my sections list to pages list(populated by index action), I get error because it expects @subject which I don't have while I am in Sections list.

I am very new to rails and I am sure I am missing something here. How do i navigate back to page list from sections list? Any ideas?

Please bear with me, I will provide more code if necessary.

Comment: So the sections list and the pages list are working fine, but when you are on pages list and click back you get an error?

Comment: Yes exactly, I do something like     (@pages = @subject.pages) to list pages for that particular subject and     (@sections =       @page.sections.sorted) to list sections for that particular page. I am maintaining that nesting that way. But when i want to get back to the pages list from sections list, maintaining that flow, I don't have     (@Subject) variable to get to the pages list. I get "pages  not defined for nil class, (@Subject)" error.